# How can I compare $\log_2 3$ and $\log_3 5$ without using a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, number-comparison

> Compare $\log_2 3$ and $\log_3 5$ without using a calculator.

I am not very good at math please explain it clearly

Comment: What have you tried? [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) a good guide on how to ask a great question.

Comment: What do you mean "compare"? I would think that you mean "which is larger?", but there are _many_ ways to compare numbers.

Comment: For the upvoters: This might be an interesting problem, but it is, at the moment, a very poorly phrased question. If you want to show it recognition for being an interesting question, or you are interested in knowing the answer, consider favouriting instead.

Comment: I think it's clear that comparison in this context is talking about which is larger ... no need to be pedantic about it

Comment: this question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415500/which-is-bigger-among-i-log-2-3-and-log-3-5-ii-log-2-3-and-log

Answer (score 9):

Note:
$$\log_2 3=\frac14 \log_2 81>\frac14\log_2 64=\frac64=\frac32,$$
$$\log_3 5=\frac14 \log_3 625<\frac14\log_3 729=\frac64=\frac32.$$

Answer (score 3):

We'll prove that $$\log_35<\log_23$$ or
$$5<3^{\log_23}$$ or
$$25<3^{\log_29},$$
which is true because
$$3^{\log_29}>3^{\log_28}=27>25.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{3}\approx 1.73,\sqrt{2}\approx 1.42\\2^{1.5}=2\sqrt{2}< 2.84,\ 3^{1.5}=3\sqrt{3}>5.19\\\log_2 3>\log_22.84>\log_22\sqrt2= 1.5=\log_33\sqrt{3}> \log_35.19>\log_3 5$$